# Headless tests using Poltergeist plugin Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm trying to run just a simple headless browser test using the Poltergeist driver.  When I try to connect to the webpage,  I get the following message:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
```

I've tried adding the `phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']` line to my env file yet it still doesn't connect.

Would there be any other solutions out there.

I use Poltergeist 1.5.1 and phantomjs 1.8.1.  Capybara 2.2.1.

Could it be a compatibility issue?

Any help would be great

Comment: PhantomJS 1.8.1 is really old. Maybe use 1.9.7 with `--ssl-protocol=any` or simply 1.9.8?

Comment: Thank you, I updated to 1.9.8 and I had to add the following after seeing your line of code: phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],